# SocketException when creating new InternetExplorerDriver with Selenium 2.7.0

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, socketexception

I'm trying to create a new instance of the Selenium InternetExplorerDriver to run a simple test and I'm receiving the following exception message:

```
SocketException occurred
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ::1:56335
```

What exactly is it trying to connect to at this point? I've tried setting proxy settings for the driver with the following code but still receive the same error:

```
var proxy = new Proxy { ProxyAutoConfigUrl = "http://myworkproxy.removed.com:1234" };
var capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, proxy);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

I've had a search but can't find much documentation for the latest version of Selenium. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of Selenium (selenium-webdriver), then the `SocketException` occurred, because your code cannot connect to the Selenium Server on the default port (I believe 4444). This might be because you haven't launched the selenium server (comes as a jar file - see the Selenium home page) or there might be another application that is using the same port that you are trying to connect to.